# Theano: ifelse for three cases

Tags: if-statement, neural-network, theano

I'm trying to implement the neural network model described in [this paper](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~srush/acl15.pdf). The loss function, however, consists of a 4 part if/else block, similar to this structure:

```
if correct: loss = 0
elif <condition1>: loss = 0.5
elif <condition2>: loss = 0.2
else: loss = 0.4
```

I'm aware of the `theano.ifelse.ifelse` op. However, in order to implement this structure, there would be four nested `ifelse` cases. Is there an easier way to implement these four cases?

(For the record, I actually implemented a nested `ifelse` in theano, but I ran to the same bug as [this google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/ZEB1L7omeFc).)

Comment: Actually, even with one `ifelse` statement, I run into compiler errors: https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/4471.